# Flask can't resize the img

Tags: html, flask

I'm trying to modify the size of the picture but it is still shown on website as the original size

```
 <img src= {{ url_for('static', filename='logoblack.png', width="12" )}}>
```

Comment: flask renders/fill the variable values in the HTML and sends the page to a browser. So if you have a syntax issue with HTML, then the expected result will not match. image tag looks like  ` <img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600"> ` source : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp . So you need to change the src, and in flask, code will be <img src= "{{ url_for('static', filename='my_image.png')}}", width="500" ,height="600"> and rest remains same . hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much. know i understand

Comment: glad that it helped. I have put this in answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

`flask` renders/fills the variable values in the HTML and sends the page to a browser. So if you have a syntax issue with HTML, then the expected result will not match. The image tag looks like

```html
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
```

Check [w³schools on *HTML Images*](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp).

So you need to change the `src`, and in flask, code will be

```
<img src= "{{ url_for('static', filename='my_image.png')}}",
     width="500" ,height="600">
```

and rest remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `width` to the `img` tag, not the `{{ <link> }}` dynamic content as seen here

```py
<img style="max-width: 50%; height: auto;" src="{{'static', filename='logoblack.png')}}" alt="<name>">
```